# How to prevent Just-In-Time Debugger showing when script error occurs in WebBrowser control

Tags: winforms, jit, web-controls

I use a WebBrowser control in my Winforms application. When I navigate to a Url that causes a JavaScript exception the Just-In-Time (JIT) debugger window shows up asking if you want to debug this exception:

> An Unhandled exception ('Object
>   expected') occured in (application)

This happens (in Release mode) even though I set the **ScriptErrorsSuppressed** on the WebBrowser control to **True**. I could only reproduce the issue when Visual Studio was installed so I assume that the JIT debugger catches the exception and then ask if you want to Debug.

How can I prevent this from happening? What I am trying to do is catch the exception or disable JIT debugging for my application **without having to reconfigure IE or Visual Studio.**

Some of our users have Visual Studio installed and these JIT popups make our application unusable.

Answer (score 1):

See this link for how to disable the JIT debugger.  The short version is open Visual Studio as an Admin and navigate to Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> JIT Debugging

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8kf6y2a.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. What I am trying to do is deactivate JIT debugging for my application (not on my machine) - so that customers (even if they have debugging tools installed) will not see this message.